# Удаление строки из файла при выполнении условия

Tags: c++, файлы

Необходимо удалить все элементы, у которых год выпуска меньше заданного.

Вот код: создаёт файл и мы записываем туда структуру, но мне надо потом ввести год и программа должна удалить все строки, у которых год выпуска меньше заданного. Как это сделать?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct avto
{
    string mark;
    string cost;
    string year;
    string cvet;
};
int main()
{ 
    int MAX;
    cout <<"vvedite col-vo avto\n";
    cin>>MAX;
    avto b[MAX];
    for (int i=0;i<MAX;++i)
    {
        cout << "Enter mark :" << endl; 
        cin >> b[i].mark;
        cout << "Enter cost :" << endl;
        cin >> b[i].cost;
        cout << "Enter year :" << endl;
        cin >> b[i].year;
        cout << "Enter cvet :" << endl;
        cin >> b[i].cvet;
   }

   ofstream outfile;
   outfile.open("Out.txt");
   for (int i=0;i<MAX;++i)
   {
       outfile << b[i].mark << " " << b[i].cost << " " << b[i].year << " " << b[i].cvet << endl;
   }
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) Открываем файл с записями (ф1) на чтение. 2) Открываем новый файл (ф2) на запись. 3) читаем по очереди записи из ф1, если запись удовлетворяет условию (например год больше заданного), записываем запись в ф2. 4) закрываем файлы и заменяем ф1 на ф2.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Отформатируйте как следует и хватит плодить одинаковые вопросы, вы там за всю группу задания постите что ли?

Comment: Вам уже объясняли основной алгоритм: 1) Открываем файл на чтение. 2) читаем по очереди строки из файла, если строка удовлетворяет условию, записываем её в во временную строковую переменную. 3) закрываем файл 4) открываем тот же файл на перезапись, записывам полученную в пункте 2 строку.

Comment: Ах да, самое главное забыл, вы хоть добавьте в описание вопроса разяснение проблемы, что именно в коде не работает? Ну или хотя бы опишите словами то, что код должен делать и вам быстро напишут какой-нибудь вариант решения (просто ваши вопросы очень размытые мягко говоря). И, все-таки, отформатируйте код в вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct avto {
    string mark;
    string cost;  // Лучше хранить как float или double
    string year;  // Лучше хранить как целое число
    string cvet;
};

bool record_fit_your_condition(avto record) {
    static string min_year = "2010";
    return record.year.compare(min_year) > 0;
}

int main()
{ 
   int MAX;
   cout <<"vvedite col-vo avto\n";
   cin>>MAX;
   avto b[MAX];
   for (int i=0;i<MAX;++i)
   {
       cout << "Enter mark :" << endl; 
       cin >> b[i].mark;
       cout << "Enter cost :" << endl;
       cin >> b[i].cost;
       cout << "Enter year :" << endl;
       cin >> b[i].year;
       cout << "Enter cvet :" << endl;
       cin >> b[i].cvet;
    }

    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("Out.txt");
    for (int i=0;i<MAX;++i)
    {
        outfile << b[i].mark << " " << b[i].cost << " " << b[i].year << " " << b[i].cvet << endl;
    }
    outfile.close();

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("Out.txt");
    ofstream outfile1;
    outfile1.open("Temp.txt");
    avto record;
    for (int i=0; i<MAX; ++i) {
        infile >> record.mark >> record.cost >> record.year >> record.color; // от cvet - кровь из глаз, уж извините
        if (record_fit_your_condition(record))
             outfile1 << record.mark << " " << record.cost << " " << record.year << " " << record.color << endl;
     }
     infile.close();
     outfile.close();
     std::remove("Out.txt");
     std::rename("Temp.txt", "Out.txt");
     system("pause");
}
```

Как-то так, только проверьте, давно ничего не читал из файлов.

Comment: у меня выдает ошибку на скобки

Comment: Точку с запятой расставили (я там пропустил в паре мест)? На какие скобки? Этот код должен быть внутри main, ну и Ваш outfile закрыть нужно сначала.

Comment: на эти скобки  {  }

Comment: то я добавила)0

Comment: как тут вписать код? тут превышение 1324 символа

Comment: #include <iostream>
          #include <fstream>
          #include <string>

          using namespace std;

           struct avto
          {
            string mark;
            string cost;
            string year;
           string color;
            };

Comment: 'int main()
{ 
    int MAX;
    cout <<"vvedite col-vo avto\n";
    cin>>MAX;
    avto b[MAX];
    for (int i=0;i<MAX;++i)
    {
        cout << "Enter mark :" << endl; 
        cin >> b[i].mark;
        cout << "Enter cost :" << endl;
        cin >> b[i].cost;
        cout << "Enter year :" << endl;
        cin >> b[i].year;
        cout << "Enter color :" << endl;
        cin >> b[i].color;
   }'

Comment: Проверьте, я написал код целиком, и напишите на какую строчку ругается.

Comment: ofstream outfile;

Comment: if ( record_fit_your_condition(record))

Comment: ofstream outfile;

Comment: [Error] redeclaration of 'std::ofstream outfile'
'std::ofstream outfile' previously declared here
[Error] 'record_fit_your_condition' was not declared in this scope

Comment: как тут в комментариях вписать код? через одинарные кавычки не хочет и превышение пишет здесь...я прост недавно зарегистрировалась

Comment: сейчас я весь вписала ваш код
выдает ошибку на     return record.year > min_year;

Comment: Ну да, у Вас же там строки... Сейчас поправлю\

Comment: хорошо))  спасибо)))

Answer (score 0):

Ну, первая ошибка - комментарий начинается с `//`, а не `\\` :)

А вторая и главная - вы объявили `record.year` как `string`, но сравниваете это поле с `int`. Что больше - "литр" или 15? - примерно так у вас получилось.

Это ответ на ваш конкретный вопрос, но это еще не все ошибки. Намекну, например, что при объявлении массива его размер должен быть известен при компиляции.

Comment: а какие еще ????

Comment: @Софья  Ну я же указал вторую. третья - думаю, стоимость тоже не стоит делать строкой. Далее, если вы попробуете ввести как марку машины, например, `Volkswagen Passat` - как два слова - то второе слово окажется ценой.
Думаю, пока хватит.

Comment: @Harry, это, на самом деле, моя ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Начнем с мелочи - вы пишете в файл, открытый для чтения. Но это мелочь. Посмотрите сами, что делает ваша программа во второй части: считывает и выводит кучу записей из файла (надеюсь, что он есть и не пуст...), затем пытается проверить последнюю (не помню уж, формально - не имеет ли права `fread` испортить память при ошибке чтения), и если она проходит условие - пытаетесь дописать ее в конец файла, открытого для чтения. *"Где же логика?!" (с) Анекдот про Вовочку.*

И еще - если вы так пишете код, не форматируя - вы мешаете сами себе. Поймите, всякие отступы и т.п. - это не придирки преподавателя. Согласитесь, что такой код, как показан ниже, гораздо проще понимать. А современные редакторы по сути сами его делают таким (вопрос скорее - как вам удается так его корежить?)

И еще - это вот, несмотря на применение `cin` - никак не С++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
struct avto
{
    char mark[20];
    char color[30];
    int year;
    float cost;
};

void main ()
{
    avto p;
    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("D:\\f44.txt","w");
    int n;
    printf("\n kol-?");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("\n mark: ");
        scanf("%s",&p.mark);
        printf("\n color: ");
        scanf("%s",&p.color);
        printf("\n Year: ");
        scanf("%d",&p.year);
        printf("\n Cost: ");
        scanf("%f",&p.cost);

        fwrite(&p,sizeof(avto),1,f);
    }
    fclose(f);

    f=fopen("D:\\f55.txt","r");
    while(fread(&p,sizeof(avto),1,f))
    {
        printf("\n%s %s %d %f",p.mark,p.color,p.year,p.cost);
    }
    int yearmin;
    cout<<"введите год";
    cin>>yearmin;
    if(p.year>yearmin)
        fwrite(&p,sizeof(avto),1,f);
    fclose(f);
    getch ();
}
```