# помогите найти ошибку работа с файлами с++

Tags: c++

в чем ошибка программы???

```
       #include <cstdio>
       #include <iostream>
      #include <fstream>
      #include <string>
      using namespace std;

      struct avto {
      string mark;
      string cost;
      string year;
      string color;
      };

      bool record_fit_your_condition(avto record) {
      static int min_year = 2010;
     return record.year > min_year;\\здесь выдает ошибку(((((((
     }

    int main()
    { 
    int MAX;
    cout <<"vvedite col-vo avto\n";
   cin>>MAX;
    avto b[MAX];
    for (int i=0;i<MAX;++i)
    {
   cout << "Enter mark :" << endl; 
   cin >> b[i].mark;
   cout << "Enter cost :" << endl;
   cin >> b[i].cost;
   cout << "Enter year :" << endl;
   cin >> b[i].year;
   cout << "Enter cvet :" << endl;
   cin >> b[i].color;
}

ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("Out.txt");
for (int i=0;i<MAX;++i)
{
    outfile << b[i].mark << " " << b[i].cost << " " << b[i].year << " " << b[i].color << endl;
}
outfile.close();

ifstream infile;
infile.open("Out.txt");
ofstream outfile1;
outfile1.open("Temp.txt");
avto record;
for (int i=0; i<MAX; ++i) {
    infile >> record.mark >> record.cost >> record.year >> record.color; 
    if (record_fit_your_condition(record))
         outfile1 << record.mark << " " << record.cost << " " << record.year            << " " << record.color << endl;
 }
 infile.close();
 outfile.close();
 remove("Out.txt");
rename("Temp.txt", "Out.txt");
 system("pause");
    }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Удаление строки из файла при выполнении условия](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/490276/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8f)