# удаление из файла с++

Tags: c++

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct avto
{
    char mark[20];
    char color[30];
    int year;
    float cost;
};

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    avto p;
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("D:\\f44.txt", "w");

    int n;
    printf("\n kol-?");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("\n mark: ");
        scanf("%s", &p.mark);
        printf("\n color: ");
        scanf("%s", &p.color);
        printf("\n Year: ");
        scanf("%d", &p.year);
        printf("\n Cost: ");
        scanf("%f", &p.cost);

        fwrite(&p, sizeof(avto), 1, f);
    }

    fclose(f);
    f = fopen("D:\\f55.txt", "r");
    while (fread(&p, sizeof(avto), 1, f))
    {
        printf("\n%s %s %d %f", p.mark, p.color, p.year, p.cost);
    }
    int yearmin;
    cout << "введите год";
    cin >> yearmin;
    if (p.year > yearmin)
        fwrite(&p, sizeof(avto), 1, f);
    fclose(f);
    getch();
}
```

почему не работает код?????????????????помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Ваши грустные смайлики вряд ли окажут влияние на текущее сообщество :) Просто проблема в том, что вы откуда-то копи пейстите код и не пробуете понять в чем проблема, например, [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/490276/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F) у вас был кол в стиле c++, а здесь же стиле C (тянутся всякие старперские функции).